# estimateRigidTransform(): convert resulting cv::Mat to transform/rotation information

Tags: opencv, matrix, rotation, transformation

as a result of estimateRigidTransform() I get a cv::Mat object that seems to contain a matrix. Unfortunately it is a bit unclear for me what is in data-field exactly.

So my question: how can I extract the transformation / rotation part our of that cv::Mat or how can I convert this cv::Mat to a standard (e.g. 3x3) matrix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html) says that its output is a 2x3 transformation matrix, you could verify this by

```
std::cout<<your_matrix <<std::endl;
```

If you want to convert it to a 3x3 matrix instead, simply add [0,0,1] as the third row.